# Social media like profile page URL's in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

In my spring boot web application there are users. What i want to do is creating private URLs for every profile like in most social media web sites.

For example ;

www.example.com/jennifer

www.example.com/david

in php using redirecting links with .htaccess file was the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^username=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:userinfo\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^username=([^&\s]+)&username=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:userinfo\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ userinfo.php?username=$1&r [L,QSA]
```

How can i implement this in spring boot mvc web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens of ways you could do that, but at the top of my head, you can use `@Controller`, [ModelAndView](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) and a template to do the job

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public ModelAndView userPage(@PathVariable String username) {
        User userFromDatabase = someMethodThatGetsYourUserFromTheDatabase(username);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("userInfo");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", userFromDatabase);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

The above implies that you have a view named `userInfo` (e.g. a template like Thymeleaf or even JSP).

By using the above, going to `/bob` or `/potato` will display the view `userInfo`, though you might want to check if the user exists before returning the view, in which case you could return them to a page that says *"The user you're looking for does not exist"*.

You might want to read http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view or https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/ for some basic examples.

Comment: thanks for quick answer so in my spring configuration do i have to delete anyRequest().authenticated(); or is there a specific pattern to implement antMatchers("/{username}").permitAll()